# What is the fastest way to strip a single GET parameter from a URL in PHP?

Tags: php, get, redirect

Example:

The user calls:

```
http://www.example.com/?mysecret=hello&second=world&third=bar
```

If "mysecret" is correct a cookie is set and user shall be redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/?second=world&third=bar
```

Code sample:

```
if(is_page(MY_LOCKED_PAGE)) {

if($_COOKIE["unlocked"]=="y") {
    // proceed
} else if(isset($_GET["mysecret"])) {
    setcookie('unlocked','y',time()+3600*24*180,'/',"",false,true);

    // strip mysecret from the URL

    // redirect to the original URL without the get parameter "mysecret", but keeping other get parameters

} else {
    // redirect 404
}
}
```

Fill in the missing code - what is the fastest way to strip the parameter mysecret and redirect to the same url?

Comment: `header("Location: ./?second=world&third=bar");` ?

Comment: Use `unset($_GET["mysecret"])` to remove it.

Comment: Ofc. but lets assume I do not know what the other get parameters are. The question is for the fastest way to split and reparse the url.

Comment: @alpha maybe i thought to complicated i ll try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) your `mysecret` and harness [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to generate the new url from the `$_GET` super global:

```
unset($_GET['mysecret']);
$url = http_build_query($_GET);
// redirect
header("Location: {$url}");
```

And here's an [**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#FNjT8vdS4).

Comment: Basically correct however I posted the full answer which worked for me (maybe a shorter solution is possible).

Answer (score 0):

The full answer which worked for me is as below:

```
    unset($_GET['mysecret']);

    $build = http_build_query($_GET);

    $uri_parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);

    $prot = "http://";

    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
            $prot = "https://";
        }
    }

    $url = $prot . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $uri_parts[0] . "?" . $build;

    // redirect
    header("Location: {$url}"); die;
```